# question about parametric derivative.

Tags: calculus, analysis

In thomas calculus, if y=g(t), x=f(t), f,g is differentiable at t, and dy/dx exist and f'(t)$\neq 0$
imply $$dy/dx=g'(t)/f'(t)$$

I wonder then there exist a example s.t f,g is differentiable at t, and f'(t)is not zero but dy/dx is not exist?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such example. If $f$ is differentiable and $f'(t)\neq 0$ in some neighborhood of $t=t_0$, there is an inverse function defined in a neighborhood of $f(t_0)$, that is $t=h(x)$ for some differentiable $h$. To show this, just use the contrapositive of Rolle's Theorem. Then the composition $y=g(t)=g(h(x))$ is a differentiable function of $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0=f(t_0)$ and $y'(x)$ is given by the chain rule.

Observe that you need to assume $f'(t)\neq 0$ in some interval, not just at the point $t_0$, since you are not assuming continuous differentiability.